# Does STS support a local Groovy installation?

Tags: eclipse, grails, groovy, ide

So far I've been writing apps with Groovy+Grails using Notepad++. I don't tend to like IDEs getting in my way, especially since apparently STS is convinced that it has to do everything with batteries included, which means bundling its own installation of Groovy via the Groovy-Eclipse plugin. A project I'm working on is now getting so large that switching to an IDE would be best, but an even bigger plus would be if I could get STS to point to my local Groovy installation, as it does with the Grails plugin.

How can I get STS to use a local Groovy compiler as opposed to its built-in ones?

Comment: what's wrong with using the built in Groovy compiler?

Comment: It's a matter of personal preference, mostly.

Comment: I don't see any options to point to local groovy installation but using Eclipse 4.2 (Juno) with STS I've three options for Groovy compiler: 1.7.10.xx, 1.8.6.xx, 2.0.0.xx - this should probably satisfy  your needs. Under ".../eclipse/plugins/org.codehaus.groovy_.../lib there are libs but I wouldn't try to override them.

Comment: I doubt there would be any (significant) differences between the groovy version/compiler in the IDE compared to what you have locally and you get all the benefit of the tooling and upgrades etc. I've certainly found STS to be great to work in.

Comment: STS makes annoying, modal error boxes appear every so often, and I never got the 1.8 compiler to work (who knows?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Groovy-Eclipse has deep hooks into Eclipse's Java compiler as well as into Groovy's compiler.  In fact, it ships with a patched version of both.  This is the way that you can get incremental compilation, eager parsing, content assist, joint compilation (without using a stub compiler), etc.  For this reason, Groovy-Eclipse does not support an external compiler.

Comment: Great answer! Old habits die hard, I suppose. Not long ago I was working with Linux using the good 'ol command line and makefiles, managing the entire toolchain myself.